# Redirecting Customers from Facebook or Twitter to My Site

Tags: marketing

I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this question (close if necessary)

I have my Facebook page for my website which I am doing my advertising for. I want to have different coupons for different campaigns (say, a Christmas campaign) and redirect them to my site.

My question: Is it good to redirect users to a custom landing page on my site 
eg: http://mysite.com/facebookad and show different content or should I just do http://mysite.com/?ref=facebookad and keep the same content up?

I'm new to marketing so I'm not sure who to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two separate issues** here:

- Content

The content question is a purely marketing one. You could make pages specific to a particular type of user (e.g., "facebook-like page" for people coming from Facebook), or you can have a generic page with just a small indication of where the user came from, or no difference at all between pages.

- Landing page URL

The landing page URL can take, in my experience, one of three different forms:

- Subdomain: facebook.example.com
- Page: example.com/facebook
- Parameters: example.com/?ref=facebook

What many people do not realize is that these can **ALL BE THE SAME PAGE**. This is generally fairly easy using WordPress and other content management systems, at least for Page vs. Parameters. Subdomains get a little more complicated but are often relatively easy as well.

I highly recommend either subdomains or pages as they make it easy for the user to remember or to write down. While most users on most sites come through clicks, you'd be surprised how often people write down, or just try to memorize, a URL. If the URL is really short and "just words", it is easy to remember or write down and easy to type in. From best to worst:

- facebook.example.com - just remember your domain and "facebook"
- example.com/facebook - just remember your domain and "facebook", but also need that /
- example.com/?ref=facebook - need to also remember "?ref="
- example.com/?ref=123 - need to remember a meaningless ID #
- example.com/referral/123 - need to remember extra slashes

A very important part of this is to make sure, when possible, that partial URLs will work. It is typically not hard to make (using the above examples):

- example.com
- example.com/?ref=facebok - misspelled ref
- example.com/?ref=124 - wrong ref ID
- example.com/?ref- forgot last parameter
- example.com/ref123 - forgot ? and =
  etc.

all come to a reasonable looking page instead of a nasty-looking 404.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred to create Facebook ad post/visual with similarities of your site's actual content and main Call To Acrion. Otherwise, how many times would you recreate the ad content and align an ad landing page accordingly? The rule of thumb to retain users  redirecting from an ad is the relevancy of content. Promise some content on the ad and satisfy them with your actual detailed content.

You can navigate them to the coupon section tagged with an id on your page too. If this is what you think they need the most.